# Not able to setup BitBucket ALM with SonarQube

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, bitbucket

I am currently on SonarQube Community Edition and I am trying to Integrate SonarQube with BitBucket. I have created an OAuth Consumer in my BitBucket Account and when I try to add it in SonarQube's BitBucket Cloud I am getting an error which is not properly complete I Guess (Unknown url : /api/alm_settings/create_bitbu... )

I don't know what I am doing wrong or if SonarQube Community Edition doesn't allow me to integrate BitBucket ALM. [I am attaching a screenshot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tFp8.jpg)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I have solved this issue and am posting the solution for whoever needs it.

It just so happens that this was an issue with the version of SonarQube I had. I updated SonarQube to the latest version(v9.6.1) and that resolved my issue.

Cheers,